# Apply position absolute style using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, absolute

I am building a site with a right aligned nav.

The last menu item drop down runs off the page as it is positioned absolute to the left of its parent.

I am trying to create a solution for my menu below.

`jsfiddle -`http://jsfiddle.net/ashconnolly/6gjVr/

I cannot hardcode the pos left -xx style, because the width of the last menu item will vary (due to the text inside it), hence my use of js.
I've nearly cracked it, but i just need to apply a variable as a position absolute left style only on hover.
There maybe a better css only solution, but i couldn't find one.

Any help is appreciated! :D

Edit: updated explanation.

Comment: In your fiddle you already calculate the `leftval`, so why you don't simply set it as a value for `left` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already calculated the left of your last menu, why didn't you use?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var menuitemwidth = document.getElementById("last-menu-item").offsetWidth;
var menuitemdropdownwidth = document.getElementById("last-menu-item-drop-down").offsetWidth;
//alert(menuitemwidth);
var leftval = menuitemdropdownwidth - menuitemwidth;
//alert(leftval);
    $("#last-menu-item").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#last-menu-item-drop-down").css({'position':'absolute','left':'-'+leftval+'px','display':'block'});
    });
    $("#last-menu-item").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#last-menu-item-drop-down").css({'display':'none'});
    });

});
```

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gjVr/12/)

Comment: Booooom! thats done it!
Yeh i managed to calculate it, it was applying it that i had trouble with. So I'm guessing to reference javascript variables in jQuery you use +varname+? cool! 
Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad to hear that sound -: Boooom!

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already know, it is bad practice to "print" javascript values using a framework. It will pretty soon become unmaintainable.

But you **can** separate (element) logic from (element) presentation, i.e. print/format html elements in your templates by setting a `data-attribute` like this in your html:

```
<ul id="last-menu-item-drop-down" data-pos="left" data-val="-133px">
```

Then change your javascript to:

```
// cache last element, no need to jquery search on every hover
var last_elem = $("#last-menu-item-drop-down");

// set position and alignment
last_elem.css('position','absolute').css(last_elem.data("pos"), last_elem.data("val"));

// set dropdown meny visibility to hidden (do it by css)
last_elem.hide()

// show/hide
// ...
```

You can also do the offset calculations in javascript and only specify position in your templates

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/cYsp6/7/

Comment: Oh so its bad practice to print my javascript variable inside jQuery?
I'd rather do it all in js where possible.
You lost me with the logic presentation separation bit though! why is it better to use data-pos as oppose to direct css changes?
thanks again!

Comment: http://nateabele.com/semantic-markup-i and http://nateabele.com/semantic-markup-ii sum it up better than I ever would be able to ;)

Answer (score 0):

I cant Make with css

```
$("#last-menu-item").mouseenter(function(){
var a=-(parseInt($("#last-menu-item-drop-down").css('width'))-parseInt($("#last-menu-item").css('width')));
 $("#last-menu-item-drop-down").css('position','absolute').css('left',a);
 $("#last-menu-item-drop-down").show();
});
$("#last-menu-item").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#last-menu-item-drop-down").hide();
});
```

Updated Fiddle:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gjVr/9/)

Comment: Sorry mate i wasnt clear in my post. I cannot hardcode the position left like you have the width of the last menu entry will vary. it will likely be cms driven so the text inside it will change.
Thanks for the help though!